# Windows Azure - frequent protocol violations with content-length mismatches

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm working on altering an existing self-hosted ASP.NET web application to run in Windows Azure.  I've successfully deployed the application to a web role and initially at a glance everything seemed to be working okay.

However, I quickly started noticing that Javascript wasn't executing on many of the pages as I was expecting it to.  Further investigation revealed that many of the pages are not fully loading.  I've been using Firefox (which is apparently more forgiving) and it renders the partial content, whereas IE simply displays "Page cannot be displayed".

Running fiddler or charles I can see that protocol violations are occurring with content-length mismatches (the server sets the content-length response header to one value but then does not return the full content.

The length of the content actually returned seems to vary, so I haven't been able to find a link to a response length cap or anything like that.  Here are a few example error messages from fiddler:

> Fiddler has detected a protocol violation in session #27.
> Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 26,716 bytes, but
> server sent 23,138 bytes.
>
> Fiddler has detected a protocol violation in session #47.
> Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 54,444 bytes, but
> server sent 32,546 bytes.
>
> Fiddler has detected a protocol violation in session #80.
> Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 27,152 bytes, but
> server sent 18,726 bytes.

This behavior does not occur in the app when run locally using the Azure compute emulator or in the original on-premise application - it only occurs when deployed to Azure itself.

In case it helps, the web application is an ASP.NET 2.0 app running under .NET 3.5 SP1.

Any ideas about what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Is the content correct - is anything missing? Is it compressed, but the content-encoding header isn't set?

Comment: The content that comes across is correct, but it looks as if it has been truncated.  If I compare it to what comes across locally using the Azure compute emulator the content matches but abruptly ends - often in the middle of a tag.

Comment: That's very peculiar. Anything untoward in the logs? In particular, any unhandled ThreadAbort exceptions raised while your content is being rendered? Classic Web Forms or MVC?

Answer (score 3):

I should have tried this sooner, but after posting this question I had the idea of accessing the application in Azure from outside our corporate network and was surprised to find that I did not experience any of the issues described above.

So that narrows this down to be an issue with our corporate network that is causing issues with this domain for some reason.  Our IT team is still investigating the root cause, but I have confirmed that this does not appear to be an issue related to Azure itself.

Thanks for the responses.